# Pixels of UIImage / char interpretation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, colors, char

The following code translates a jpg into a string of chars.

```
 CGImageRef imageRef = example.CGImage;
    NSData *data     = (NSData *) CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef));
    char *pixels     = (char *)[data bytes];
```

a small piece of the output is:

`"GJYˇKO[ˇFJSˇILQˇKNSˇKKSˇOOYˇMMYˇNNVˇOOWˇOOWˇNNVˇLLTˇKKSˇMMUˇOOWˇJMT"`

I guess the 3 Symbols together consist of the infomation of one pixel, right?
And if this is true, how can i interpret this Symbols (colors e.g.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will all depend on the color space of your image. If there is an alpha channel 4 `char`s will be one pixel and without it will be 3 `char`s. If it is `RGBA` then G is your `R`, J is your `G` , Y is your `B` and ˇ is your `A`. And if it is `ARGB` it G is your `A` etc.. Also when you convert your pixels to a char * remember to keep track of the length because any RGBA value of 0 will cause a null termination.

Comment: thank you! do you maybe know how i can get the info about the color layout?

Comment: `CGColorGetColorSpace(imageRef)` http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGColor/Reference/reference.html

Comment: I would also ask yourself why you are converting the bytes to a char*, if it is for fun or some kind of cool feature have at it, if it is performance or storage you may want to reconsider. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't print out a bit map like that. As @Joe says the char's are the individual color components but any zero will terminate the string and there are many other problems trying to print the bytes from an NSData like that.

Assuming the RGBA color space, the way I'd approach it is like this;

```
struct {
    char red;
    char green;
    char blue;
    char alpha;
} color;
color *bitmap = (color *)[data bytes];
for(int i = 0;i < [data length] / sizeof(color);i++) {
    NSLog(@"%d, %d, %d, %d", colors[i].red, colors[i].green, colors[i].blue, colors[i].alpha);
}
```

If your image is not in the RGBA color space then you will need to adjust the color struct to match it.

Also, this code was not compiled but typed from my mind to this post. No promise is made that it won't reformat your hard drive. Please think before copy and paste.